# Why two parallel arrays are faster than single array for storing tuples

Tags: android, arrays, performance

Android developer guide mentions the following point

> If you need to implement a container that stores tuples of (Foo,Bar) objects, try to remember that two parallel `Foo[]` and `Bar[]` arrays are generally much better than a single array of custom (Foo,Bar) objects.

Could somebody help me understand why using two parallel arrays is faster?

Comment: Storing them in tuples will at the very least take up more memory. You'd also need to use an `Object[]` instead of two `int[]`s, and afaik, primitive arrays are faster than object arrays.

Comment: Could you link to the source of this quote?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you're reading this page: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips

The idea behind what they're saying is that every object instance incurs a small amount of memory overhead. Therefore, one array of many `Tuple` objects each holding one `Foo` and one `Bar` will have more overhead than two arrays (one of `Foo` objects and one of `Bar` objects).

This increase in memory consumption *might* cause the garbage collector to run more frequently, and each garbage collection action will pause your app (though it will only pause it for tiny fractions of a second).

However, keep in mind that this article is *very* old. You can get a sense of exactly how old it is from this line (emphasis mine):

> The concurrent garbage collector introduced in **Android 2.3** helps

These performance considerations *mattered more* when android hardware was weak and slow. Now that we're working on hardware that's orders of magnitude more powerful, the practical impact of things like this is significantly reduced.

In general, I would very much recommend **against** taking this article's advice. One array of `Tuple` objects is *much* easier to reason about, and will make your app much easier to maintain in the long run. Unless you have done specific and explicit performance measuring and determined beyond a shadow of a doubt that your application is garbage collecting too frequently, just ignore these "tips".

In fact, even this article tells you that you should probably ignore it unless you *know* you have a problem:

> Choosing the right algorithms and data structures should always be your priority

and

> **Always measure**
>
> Before you start optimizing, make sure you have a problem that you need to solve. Make sure you can accurately measure your existing performance, or you won't be able to measure the benefit of the alternatives you try.